# Is it possible to control DJI Phantom 2 Vision (plus) with smartphone?

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm checking at DJI specification for Phantom 2 Vision and Phantom 2 Vision plus and also API reference, but I'm not sure wether is it possible to pilot drone without remote controller? How is the communication via SDK done - is smartphone directly communicating with drone, or is going via remote controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DJI SDK Level 2 does allow direct flight control of the DJI Phantom 2 Vision+. It communicates the commands to the unit using wifi. That being said, the wifi extender that your phone is connected to is attached to the controller, so you still need the controller to be turned on and in the vicinity in order to operate, but the device is still what is sending the commands to the Phantom. I would recommend that someone always have the controller at the ready incase the wifi network has interference / phone dies etc. I am using the SDK in this way for my side project www.followmephantom.com.

Hope that helps.

FYI - to use the level SDK you first have to submit a proposal for your project to DJI and get their approval..... and pay a fee in most cases.

Here is a helpful link that shows the difference in features for the SDK level 1 and 2.
https://dev.dji.com/en/products/sdk/mobile-sdk/features/level-compare

Answer (score 0):

From 3 weeks of playing: the smart phone controls the gimbal and the camera in general, all the flight controls are strictly from the remote control unit albeit waypoints from the smart phone could be argued as control by the phone. I havent flown it without the smart phone but I am fairly sure I could, without blades on the sitting room floor it seemed possible. I cant imagine why you would want controls from your phone, when things go pear-shaped you would be pretty much screwed with just a touch screen.